# @Resource becomes null when Java Config implements AsyncConfigurer

Tags: spring, spring-java-config

I have a very strange problem. I'm using Spring 3.2.4 and have a Spring Java Config class which is part of a larger mix of Java and XML configuration files.

The file uses 6 resources defined in other config files to construct an @Async bean. When I add "implements AsyncConfigurer" to the file, some of the @Resource fields appear as null, but when I leave the implementation off, they are populated. This is confusing, since the AsyncConfigurer is just supposed be used for configuring your asynchronous executor, it shouldn't do anything funky like cause your configuration to be loaded asynchronously.

When I set a debugger on the construction method, I can see that the beans are in fact null. It seems to be a race condition of some kind, because out of the 6 beans, the 4th one was once null, and then populated the next time.

My file looks like:

```
public class UserBackgroundProcessorConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer {

    @Resource(name="bean1")
    MyBean bean1;

    // in reality there are 6 @Resources defined...

    @Resource(name="bean6")
    MyBean bean6;

    @Bean(name="backgroundProcessor")
    public BackgroundProcessor getBackgroundProcessor() {
        BackgroundProcessor backgroundProcess = new BackgroundProcessor();
        backgroundProcess.setBean1(bean1);
        // beans 1-3 are always populated
        // bean 4 seems to sometimes be populated, sometimes null
        // beans 5&6 are always null
        backgroundProcess.setBean6(bean6);

        return backgroundProcess;
    }

    @Override
    @Bean(name="executor")
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(40);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(25);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("BackgroundProcessor-");
        return executor;
    }
}
```

Again, when I remove "implements AsyncConfigurer" and comment out getAsyncExecutor, the problem goes away.

According to the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/AsyncConfigurer.html)

> Interface to be implemented by @Configuration classes annotated with @EnableAsync that wish to customize the Executor instance used when processing async method invocations.

So I don't see how that cause the behavior I am seeing.

Comment: I've tested your code, but I'm not seeing the behavior. Of course, my beanXes are just very simple beans and I assumed you have some kind of @Asynch method in BackgroundProcessor that's getting called.

Comment: @AndreiStefan - I suspect its a more complicated problem with my Spring config. The problem happens when the BackgroundProcessor is constructed, well before the Async method in the class ever gets called. Honestly it feels like a really esoteric bug in Spring

Comment: If you could isolate it and create the simplest, reproducible sample, there's always [Spring JIRA](https://jira.spring.io) where you can report it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by *removing* the @Resource annotations from the Java configuration file:

```
public class UserBackgroundProcessorConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer {

    @Bean(name="backgroundProcessor")
    public BackgroundProcessor getBackgroundProcessor() {
        BackgroundProcessor backgroundProcess = new BackgroundProcessor();
        return backgroundProcess;
    }

    @Override
    @Bean(name="executor")
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(40);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(25);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("BackgroundProcessor-");
        return executor;
    }
}
```

And then adding @Resource annotations to the BackgroundProcessor class:

```
public class BackgroundProcessor {
    @Resource private MyBean bean1;
    // 4 more
    @Resource private MyBean bean6;
}
```

For some reason this works fine. I don't like this as much, because I would prefer my classes not have a dependency on the IOC annotations, but I'll go with this solution for now.

Comment: This helped me.  I was leaving off the Bean annotation on my getAsyncExecutor method.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your `backgroundProcessor` bean is depending on your 6 resource beans.

Try annotating the method signature with:

```
@Bean(name="backgroundProcessor")
@DependsOn("bean1","bean2","bean3","bean4","bean5","bean6")
public BackgroundProcessor getBackgroundProcessor() {..}
```

Comment: Doesn't spring know that because I'm referencing them in the constructor method?

Comment: Also, any idea why this would suddenly break when I add the interface?

Comment: What do you mean they are getting referenced in the constructor? I cannot see any constructor. To your second question, the interface marks the method you are overriding and puts it into the picture. One idea is to follow the alternative that is shown in the documentation: don't mark the getAsyncExecutor() method as @Bean and perform executor.initialize() instead.

Comment: sorry, I mean the beans are referenced in getBackgroundProcessor(). According to the Spring documentation, #DependsOn is only necessary when the bean is not directly referenced: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html

Comment: I'll try removing the @Bean, but the docs don't say how that would affect this problem either: "Note: In the above example the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor is not a fully managed Spring Bean. Add the Bean annotation to the getAsyncExecutor() method if you want a fully managed bean. In such circumstances it is no longer necessary to manually call the executor.initialize() method as this will be invoked automatically when the bean is initialized."

Comment: sure I was suggesting it as a trial/error approach. Also how about annotating your beans as @Bean other than @Resource?

Comment: As an update, @DependsOn did not work, and neither did removing the Bean annotation from the executor